# google-compute-engine - Virtual Machines and billing

Tags: google-compute-engine

When i clicked through my google cloud console yesterday, i found 26 virtual machines that i disabled then (because i think that i don´t use these - but i pay for them).

> I use firebase, firestore, firestorage, firebase cloud functions and
>   app-engine / flex-engine for php and python cron-jobs.

But today, there are 26 more vms up and running and my bill goes up. Can I disable / delete these machines and disable building new ones or disable the google-compute-engine overall?

Comment: Is the autoscaling enabled ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to our documentation about [Billing for stopped instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/stopping-or-deleting-an-instance#billing_for_stopped_instances):

- Your instances are not charged for per-second usage charges in TERMINATED state but any resources attached to the virtual machine will be charged until they are deleted, such as static IPs and persistent disks.

The link[1](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/stopping-or-deleting-an-instance#billing_for_stopped_instances) will also provide you with details about the state of resources for stopped instances.

For more pricing information. I would recommend that you visit the following links: 
1- [Google Compute Engine Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing).
2- [Pricing details on each GCP product](https://cloud.google.com/pricing/list).

To know how to manage and modify your project billing settings and many more. Visit our cloud [billing documentation](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to).